# Add duplicate lines and numbers

Tags: notepad++, pspad

i have a URL list like

`http://www.blabla.com/1/1.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/1/2.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/1/3.jpg`
    ...

`http://www.blabla.com/2/1.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/2/2.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/2/3.jpg
...`

So what i need is to duplicate `http://www.blabla.com/X/` and adding numbers like:

`http://www.blabla.com/1/1.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/1/2.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/1/3.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/1/4.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/1/5.jpg
...`

`http://www.blabla.com/2/1.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/2/2.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/2/3.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/2/4.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/2/5.jpg`
...

till `20.jpg` or higher. I can change it then i think.

Is this possible?

---

Hey thanks but do not work how i want but my own fault because i changed the list to the minimum because i thought i can adjust the script myself. So here again and i try to explain it better:

`http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/saaosao-laowia-pqoaian-11.jpg  = block 1
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-12.jpg  = block 1
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-13.jpg  = block 1
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-11.jpg = block 2
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-12.jpg = block 2
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-13.jpg = block 2
....`

http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/ < That line is always the same

alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux < Is the same in each block, names and number of ''%'' are various depending on the names

saosao-laowia-pqoaian-11.jpg < Is the same in each block except the number before .jpg, number of ''-'' is various depending on the names

The numbering of the backslashes is always the same (7)

Block 1,2.. is just an example to demonstrate it better, has nothing to do with my list

And this should be the result:

`http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/saaosao-laowia-pqoaian-11.jpg

http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-12.jpg

http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-13.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-14.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-15.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-16.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-17.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-18.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-19.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-110.jpg   < ''20'' begins with 110
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/alkalqoa%makawoa%wkwiaux/ssaosao-laowia-pqoaian-111.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-11.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-12.jpg 
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-13.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-14.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-15.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-16.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-17.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-18.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-19.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-110.jpg
http://www.blabla.com/abc/uploads/pics/kdkdaap%oqunxla%dkjdujauw%ipajqw/bazwow-axkaww-poqianxh-iapaxja-111.jpg`

In this list are also some lines that begin with 21.jpg at the end

The numbering here is

`21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
210 < ''30'' begins with 210
211
212
213
214
215
216
217
218
219
220
221
222
223
224`

The total lines each block should be 24.

So, i hope this explains everything better.

Comment: no one can help?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple with the [PythonScript](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) Notepad++ plugin installed (can be installed from the plugin manager).  Just create a new script with the following code:

```
for x in range(1, 21):
    for y in range(1, 21):
        editor.addText(str.format("http://www.blabla.com/{0}/{1}.jpg\r\n", x, y))

    editor.addText("\r\n")
```

The run the script in a new document.

Comment: @IUDFGKA http://superuser.com/editing-help

Comment: can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
$content = gc 'c:\liste.txt'
$liste_neu = 'c:\liste_neu.txt'
foreach($line in $content){
  $num = [regex]::match($line,'(\d+)\.jpg$').Groups[1].Value
  switch($num){
      "11" {
           11..19 | %{$line -replace '\d+\.jpg$',"$($_).jpg"} | add-content -path $liste_neu
           110..124 | %{$line -replace '\d+\.jpg$',"$($_).jpg"} | add-content -path $liste_neu
        }
       "21" {
           21..29 | %{$line -replace '\d+\.jpg$',"$($_).jpg"} | add-content -path $liste_neu
           210..224 | %{$line -replace '\d+\.jpg$',"$($_).jpg"} | add-content -path $liste_neu
        }
        "1" {
           1..24 | %{$line -replace '\d+\.jpg$',"$($_).jpg"} | add-content -path $liste_neu
        }
}}
```